# Surprising: Java wildcard codes cannot turn to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

It is a question about using wildcards in Kotlin as the same in Java and my description will comes with multiple codes example where I tried to make them work and it may be a long question.

Recently, I want to design a series of classes in Kotlin like

```kotlin
abstract class A<out T : B> {
    abstract fun doASth()
}

interface B

open class A1<out T : B1>(
    val myB: T,
) : A<T>() {
    override fun doASth() {
        myB.doBSth(this)
    }
}

open class B1(
    open val doBSth: (A1<out B1>)->Unit = {}
) : B

// A2 missed since I cannot defined proper B2

open class B2(
    override val doBSth: (A1<out B2>)->Unit = {}  // ERROR: from A1<out B2> to A1<out B1>
):B1(doBSth)
```

There I found Kotlin cannot do wildcard out since out B2 is clearly a child of out B1.

Next comes my work.

First try: move wildcard to class announcement and I got these codes
I got first error

```kotlin
abstract class A<out T : B> {
    abstract fun doASth()
}

interface B

open class A1<out T : B1<out B1<*>>>(
    open val myB: T,
) : A<T>() {
    override fun doASth() {
        myB.doBSth(this)//              ERROR: require A<Nothing> but get A1<T>

        // SOLUTION: here if I use cast them no error but comes warning of unchecked cast
        // and I really hate that. Though I can mark no warning by annotaion, I am 
        // seeking for a better way rather than jump it.

        // By the way, this solution is the only one with no error but only warnings
        // which meaning I can go compile!!! :-)
    }
}

open class B1<T : B>(
    open val doBSth: (A<T>) -> Unit = {}
) : B

open class A2<out T : B2<out B2<*>>>(
    override val myB: T,
) : A1<T>(myB)

open class B2<T : B>(
    override val doBSth: (A<T>) -> Unit = {}
) : B1<T>(doBSth)
```

I got second error

```kotlin
abstract class A<out T : B> {
    abstract fun doASth()
}

interface B

open class A1<out T : B1< B1<*>>>(
    open val myB: T,
) : A<T>() {
    override fun doASth() {
        myB.doBSth(this)
    }
}

open class B1<T : B>(
    open val doBSth: (A<T>) -> Unit = {}
) : B

open class A2<out T : B2< B2<*>>>(
    override val myB: T,
) : A1<T>(myB) //                         ERROR: except B1<B1<*>> but got T

open class B2<T : B>(
    override val doBSth: (A<T>) -> Unit = {}
) : B1<T>(doBSth)
```

These two error tell:

1. use nest out will bring you Nothing in type analysis which is not acceptable for me:

   I use wildcard to declared all types I needed, why you just bring me Nothing!
2. Kotlin out cannot out nested type since they will be erased:

   This is problem of compile since I agree Apple<Apple> is safe to be used as Fruit<Fruit>.

Next is my final try, I wrote following codes in Java:

```java
abstract class A<T extends B> {
}

interface B {
}

class A1<T extends B1> extends A<B1> {
    public A1() {
        this.self = null;
    }

    public A1(A1<? extends B1> self) {
        this.self = self;
    }

    public A1<? extends B1> self;
}

class B1 implements B {
    public B1() {
        this.aPointer = null;
    }

    public B1(A1<? extends B1> aPointer) {
        this.aPointer = aPointer;
    }

    public A1<? extends B1> aPointer;
}

class A2<T extends B2> extends A<B2> {
    public A2() {
        this.self = null;
    }

    public A2(A2<? extends B2> self) {
        this.self = self;
    }

    public A2<? extends B2> self;
}

class B2 extends B1 {
    public B2() {
        this.aPointer = null;
    }

    public B2(A2<? extends B2> aPointer) {
        this.aPointer = aPointer;
    }

    public A2<? extends B2> aPointer;
}
```

Then I use Android Studio to convert it to Kotlin automatically, and I got

```kotlin
internal abstract class A<T : B?>
internal interface B
internal open class A1<T : B1?> : A<B1?> {
    constructor() {
        self = null
    }

    constructor(self: A1<B1>?) {
        this.self = self
    }

    var self: A1<B1>?
}

internal open class B1 : B {
    constructor() {
        aPointer = null
    }

    constructor(aPointer: A1<B1>?) {
        this.aPointer = aPointer
    }

    open var aPointer: A1<out B1>? // here I add open & out to fix convert
}

internal class A2<T : B2?> : A<B2?> {
    constructor() {
        self = null
    }

    constructor(self: A2<B2>?) {
        this.self = self
    }

    var self: A2<B2>?
}

internal class B2 : B1 {
    constructor() {
        aPointer = null
    }

    constructor(aPointer: A2<B2>?) {
        this.aPointer = aPointer
    }

    override var aPointer: A2<B2>? // here I add override to fix convert
                                   // ERROR: A2<B2> or A1<B2> is both not acceptable
}
```

That's all and as you can see, I cannot make my Java code to Kotlin and use wildcard in Kotlin as I used them in Java.

**UPDATE**

Cause name like A1&B1 is quite confusing, here updated a named example for my fisrt try above which failed on cast Nothing.

```
abstract class BaseExecutor<out T : BaseState> {
    abstract fun doSth()
}

interface BaseState

open class ExecutorG1<out T : StateG1<out StateG1<*>>>(
    open val state: T,
) : BaseExecutor<T>() {
    override fun doSth() {
        state.doSth(this)//              ERROR: require A<Nothing> but get A1<T>

        // SOLUTION: here if I use cast them no error but comes warning of unchecked cast
        // and I really hate that. Though I can mark no warning by annotaion, I am 
        // seeking for a better way rather than jump it.

        // By the way, this solution is the only one with no error but only warnings
        // which meaning I can go compile!!! :-)
    }
}

open class StateG1<T : BaseState>(
    open val doSth: (BaseExecutor<T>) -> Unit = {}
) : BaseState

open class ExecutorG2<out T : StateG2<out StateG2<*>>>(
    override val state: T,
) : ExecutorG1<T>(state)

open class StateG2<T : BaseState>(
    override val doSth: (BaseExecutor<T>) -> Unit = {},
    val moreConfig: String = "",
) : StateG1<T>(doSth)
```

**UPDATE 2**

For J's ask, here is an example of my final java codes which works:
(This look a little complex because I did't use A<? extends A> in example since it is not allowed in kotlin. Aha, that's also a difference between java & kotlin.)
(Java and koltin do have some difference and I tried my best to make my Java code similar to kotlin, there maybe improvement and suggestions is welcome)

```
// interface for lambda
interface FunctionPointer<T> {
    public void doSth(T input);
}

interface BaseState {
}

abstract class BaseExecutor<S extends BaseState> {
    public S myState;

    public abstract void doSth();
}

// G for generation
class StateG1<E extends BaseExecutor<? extends BaseState>> implements BaseState {
    public StateG1(FunctionPointer<E> partJobPointer) {
        this.partJobPointer = partJobPointer;
    }

    public FunctionPointer<E> partJobPointer;
}

class ExecutorG1<S extends StateG1<BaseExecutor<? extends StateG1<?>>>,
        E extends BaseExecutor<S>> extends BaseExecutor<S> {
    @Override
    public void doSth() {
        myState.partJobPointer.doSth(this);

        // here I treat any descendant state as G1 state, which is safe
    }
}

class StateG2<E extends BaseExecutor<? extends BaseState>> extends StateG1<E> {
    public StateG2(FunctionPointer<E> partJobPointer) {
        super(partJobPointer);
    }

    public StateG2(FunctionPointer<E> partJobPointer, Map<String, String> moreConfig) {
        super(partJobPointer);
        this.moreConfig = moreConfig;
    }

    public Map<String, String> moreConfig;
}

class ExecutorG2<S extends StateG2<BaseExecutor<? extends StateG1<?>>>,
        E extends BaseExecutor<S>> extends ExecutorG1<S, E> {

    @Override
    public void doSth() {
        super.doSth();

        // here I treat any descendant state as G2 state, which is safe

        myState.partJobPointer.doSth(this);
        myState.moreConfig.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe what you try to do with `B2` breaks the type safety and Kotlin is right that it shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @broot  yeah, that the point confusing me. I don't see where is unsafe to use Apple<Apple> as Fruit<Fruit>.

Comment: @broot and even override Fruit<Fruit> to Fruit<Apple> is not allowed, as you can see A1<B2> cannot override A1<out B1>

Comment: `A1` is a parameter to lambda, so it is implicitly contravariant. I will provide you a better example/explanation later today, if no one do this earlier.

Comment: It would help if you used your real-world example, because what you seem to be trying to do doesn't seem correct at the *conceptual* level, so it seems logical you cannot put it in code

Comment: Hello bros, my first kotlin codes are just describing mind and it's failed. My question is for two failed try and last java-koltin convert fail follows it. I hope that didn't mislead you. :-)

Comment: @michael Just to make sure I understand your updated example right. You have executors and states and you would like to make "families" of implementations, so e.g. G1 executor and state that work with each other, G2 executor and state that work with each other and so on. Is this correct?

Comment: @broot yeah, that's what I want. And key  contravariant part is I want executor to do sth with partly job stored in state.

Comment: So this is what I described as "common misunderstanding of OOP" somewhere here in comments ;-) Such concept is inherently not type safe. It is fine to have "families" of types, no problem with that. The problem is that the family G2 can't be subtypes of family G1. Why? Because when we created G1 we said that their classes can work with any other G1 classes. Now, we want to create family G2 which will work with G2 only. That makes these classes not really G1, because G1 was supposed to work with any G1, not only with some specific subtypes.

Comment: G2 tries to limit the functionality of G1 by limiting the set of types we can work with. But according to Liskov principle which is applied in virtually every programming language in the world, subtypes can only add new functionality, they can't remove or limit the functionality of their supertypes.

Comment: I think the proper solution is to not make G2 extend G1. They are separate "families" of types and can't be used interchangeably. Enforcing the compiler to allow to use G2 classes as G1 will eventually lead to `ClassCastException`, so there is no point in making G2 subtypes of G1. If you need to re-use the code of G1, use delegation and/or composition over inheritance. If for some reason you can't do that, but the logic of your application guarantees that you never mix G1 and G2 then such solution should be type safe and you can use unchecked casts, because this is exactly their purpose.

Comment: In your additional "final" Java solution, `StateG1` can take an `BaseExecutor<StateG2>`. I'm not sure you meant to allow that. You also have some redundant type arguments there (at least in the piece of code shown, maybe they are used in the real code). Apart from that, it's totally ok to express this in Kotlin: https://pl.kotl.in/K1iCBwfXw. What was the problem with the corresponding Kotlin code?

Comment: First,  I designed those classses since they do meet my demand and I don't want to talk more detailed info since that is business secrect. Second, it's right I could convert my final JAVA solution into kotlin, but I think nobody would want a FunctionPointer class in kotlin due to lambda exsiting (with lambda or Function0..classes, kotlin cannot do last example) and If I do that, I will force followers using my lib writing bad code. That is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to do in `B2` is breaking the type safety and this is why Kotlin does not allow it. You are correct `T` in `A1` is covariant (`out`), so `A1<B2>` is a subtype of `A1<B1>`. However, `A1<B1>` is used as a parameter to lambda, so this whole type is contravariant. This is similar as you would have a function in `B1` that receives `A1<B1>`. And because it is contravariant, you can't override it with its subtype, i.e. `A1<B2>`.

To show the problem with this we can use the following example. Assume B2 implements this property as:

```kotlin
override val doBSth: (A1<out B2>)->Unit = {
    val b2 = it.myB // we acquire B2 object from the provided A1
    // do something with B2 object
}
```

Now, someone creates `B2` and uses it as `B1`:

```kotlin
val b2: B1 = B2()
val a1ProvidingB1: A1<B1> = ...
b2.doBSth(a1ProvidingB1) // this is allowed, but shouldn't be - broken type safety.
```

`b2` expects that it will get `B2` object from the passed `a1ProvidingB1`. But in fact, our `a1ProvidingB1` is `A1<B1>`, so it will provide `B1` object, not `B2`. So this breaks type safety.

Now, I didn't read your all examples thoroughly, but regarding your Java example and why it works. Well, it does a much different thing. First, in Java your `aPointer` is not a lambda that receives `A1/A2`, but it is a `A1/A2` object itself. If you do the same with Kotlin code, it will start working, because then it will be covariant.

Second, in Java code `aPointer` is a field, but in Kotlin `doBSth` is a getter. We can't override fields, `aPointer` in `B2` is not overriding `aPointer` in `B1` - it is just hiding it. But `doBSth` in Kotlin has to override the function of the super class, which is a much different thing.

**Update**

Your example is problematic not due to some technical limitations of the compiler. Your example is conceptually wrong, it can't be safe, so depending on the language it will be either disallowed or the compiler will allow it, but it will break the type safety.

You need to consider what happens when your base class `MyClass` **produces** or **consumes** some other data e.g. `Bird` class and `MyClass` is subtyped. If it produces birds then subtypes can produce more specific types, e.g. `Eagle`. This is safe, because each produced eagle is also a bird. But if `MyClass` consumes birds then the subtype can't decide it will consume only eagles, because then it couldn't be represented as the `MyClass` which consumed all birds. Actually, in that case the subtype could consume all animals and that would be safe, because if the subtype can consume any animal then it surely can consume birds. But again, if we produce birds then the subtype can't produce animals, because that would mean some of them would not be birds and `MyClass` produced birds only.

So wildcards work in the opposite direction depending if the data is produced or consumed. If it is produced then subtypes can produce more specific types only (subtypes). If it is consumed, subtypes can only produce more generic types (supertypes).

In your example `A1` is a lambda parameter and that means `B1` consumes `A1`. This is why you can't use subtypes of `A1` in subtypes of `B1`. If you say `B2` only consumes `A2`, then still someone can use `B2` as `B1` and feed it with `A1` which `B2` couldn't handle. This breaks the type safety.

Also, this is why it is much different if you have lambda accepting `A1` (consume) or just `A1` itself (produce - assuming it is `val`).

Comment: Thanks for your example and sorry for my late response since I were on my weekend :-)

First, I did tried to use sth like A1<out B1> in A1, and this do help me build A1<B2> in A2 successfully, but this is not what I want.

Second, for wildcard, as far as I know( I am new to kotlin and maybe wrong ), it is syntactic sugar in both kotlin and java, there is only B1 while codes compiled. Compilers just did auto cast for us. But when we consider class tree, your example actually cast B2<A1<B2>> as subtype of B1<A1<B1>>, that is clearly unsafe since B2<A1<B2>> is subtype of B1<A1<B2>>.

Comment: for lamba in kotlin, as I learned, it is is actually classes call Function0... that provided by kotlin core lib and use member fields to handle the real body and I do not see much different between lamba and a field. If I want, I can even write (sth) -> Unit as Function0<sth>.

Comment: Personally, I think my problem is caused by kotlin compiler, it is yet not as strong as java compiler( :-|  java borns long ago ), for wildcard like out A1< out B1> , I suppose jvm bytecode of kotlin codes will add cast both to out A1 and any where used out B1, then I can convert my java code into kotlin. Recently kotlin just did cast job for A1 and simply erased B1 and this makes difference.

Comment: @michael again, you should really write your question with real types, because you're misreading broot here. The fact that you use `A1` directly in Java as opposed to `(A1)->Unit` is very different. No matter whether you use `Function0<A1>` or `(A1) -> Unit`, they are still VERY different from just `A1`. Functions are contravariant in their argument types, this is the crux of your problem

Comment: *my problem is caused by kotlin compiler, it is yet not as strong as java compiler* - Java generics are broken. They compile incorrect code successfully, while Kotlin is prevent you from writing bad generics more often

Comment: Please note that in my example I didn't even use casting operator and still I was able to break the type safety. You planned `B2` to be a subtype of `B1`, but when I just used `B2` as `B1` you said that this way I broke the type safety. This is exactly the point here and why Kotlin doesn't allow what you try to do. Because `B2` can't be used as `B1` safely. Also wildcards are not syntactic sugar. Wildcards allow to make the type system a little more flexible around generics while still guaranteeing the type safety.

Comment: Your example is problematic not due to some technical limitations of the compiler. Your example is conceptually wrong, it can't be safe, so depending on the language it will be either disallowed or the compiler will allow it, but it will break the type safety.

Comment: @Joffrey I read your commit and did some research for differences of contravariant in ARGUMENTS and FIELDS but failed to find any article talking these, could you please show me some LINK or explain it more detailed, :-)       For me, my first programming lang is C++ and I usually treat functions as a pointer and it is still a field in OOP and has it field type. And as I wrote in my question body kotlin do different for nested wildcard as Java and I do not think it is unsafe or broking type safety. Since NESTED OUT CAN STILL BE CONSUMED SAFE. That could be proved by math lang.

Comment: @michael Please see my updated answer for clarification why your example is conceptually wrong and can't be type safe.

Comment: And as I comment before, those examples are really using unsafe cast since I didn't do normal class extend but extends contravariant. Your example treat B2<A1<B2>> as subtype of B1<A1<B1>> and I its real super is B1<A1<B2>>, that's why your codes is unsafe and I use wildcard is for help myself save codes and allow static code lint and compiler to do type cast& check

Comment: Could you show me the place in my code where I do the unsafe cast? Because I don't do any explicit casts there. My code doesn't generate any compiler errors or even warnings, but it breaks the type safety. How is it possible?

Comment: @broot Now I see our divergence. Assuming we are at C++ level, you & J are right that your examples do break type safety since B2.doBSth does not accept param of B1.doBSth, I can also give an example by produce B3 extends B1 and cast it to B1 and give it B2, that will make B2 error. --------next will comes my concern cause I do not have enough chars here------- :-)

Comment: For me, I am concern on use a high-level programming lang and when I announce B1, I want IDE could derivate it as B1<A1<B1>> or B1<A2<B2>> depends on where I announce it and do cast check at where I use it, if I consume A2<B2> as A1<B1>, that should be allowed, otherwise, I want a warning or error for risk cast.         -------Where you did unsafe cast---------For your codes, that's safe since you did't provide initialize T for B2 and it is default to * which means you are initializing sth that could accept anything, and use of B2.doBSth shall be safe since *<*> can be A1<B1>

Comment: If you announce B2 correctly, you may use val b2: B1 =B2<A2<B2>> to given enough info for wildcard derivation and IDE&compiler will know B1 is B1<A2<B2>> and your later codes shall be marked warning or error. That is what JAVA just doing.

Comment: @michael [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47) explains what generic variance is. Note that the variance of a generic type is defined with respect to one of its type parameters. When there is only one type parameter it's obvious, but some generic types have several type parameters. A function type `(T)->U` (or `Function1<T, U>`) has 2 type parameters, so we have to specify which one when talking about variance. Such function type is contravariant in T (its argument type) but covariant in U (its return type).

Comment: @michael `B1` and `B2` don't accept A-type type parameters, in most of your snippets they are not even generic. So what does it mean to write `B2<A2<B2>>`? Please use your real-life types to avoid mixing things up, it would help us show with clearer examples why it doesn't work, and what you could do to enfore your real expectations.

Comment: @Joffrey Thanks for you link and I'll read it later. B2<A2<B2>> can be seen in my first try code in top question body.

Comment: And sorry for use such meaning less codes cause I design those class for my company and I got to keep the detailed secret, next time I will use better name like birds, animals or friuts.

Comment: @Joffrey I'm not sure if real types would help us that much here. To me this case seems similar to a pretty common misunderstanding of OOP. People often try to implement the solution where they have e.g. base classes/interfaces `File` and `Directory` and then specific implementations `LocalFile/Dir` and `AwsFile/Dir` where locals work only with locals and AWS only with AWS. This is against Liskov principle, because we limit the functionality in subtypes instead of extending the functionality. OP's case reminds me these cases, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @broot that's exactly what real types would help us to rule out, though. Or at least types like animals and fruit. The point is to make it obvious when the problem is conceptual. Here with hypotheticals we're still not 100% sure whether OP is just failing to express a valid need in code, or if the need itself is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

> Kotlin cannot do wildcard out since out B2 is clearly a child of out B1.

Not sure what you mean by this, but as @broot already mentioned in the comments, what you're trying to achieve (at least in the first snippet) is conceptually flawed.

In particular `B2` IS-NOT a `B1`, because an instance of `B1` must have a `doBSth` that accepts any instance of `A1<out B1>`. But your definition of `B2`'s `doBSth` only accepts a subset of those.

To put it in technical terms, functions are contravariant in their argument types, so the function type `(A1<out B2>)->Unit` is not a subtype of `(A1<out B1>)->Unit`, because it would require `A1<out B1>` to be a subtype of `A1<out B2>` (the opposite of what you provide).

We can demonstrate that your first definition doesn't work. Imagine you were allowed to define `B2` like you did, now this would compile fine but would be broken:

```kotlin
val b2ViewedAsB1: B1 = B2 { arg: A<B2> -> println("I only want A<B2>") }

val aRealB1: B1 = B1 { arg: A<B1> -> println("I can handle all A<B1>") }

// must be allowed per B1's definition, yet B2 can't deal with this
b2ViewedAsB1.doBSth(A1<B1>(aRealB1))
```

> this solution is the only one with no error but only warnings

Well you had an error, but you're desperately trying to hide it. Adding an unsafe cast and suppressing the associated warning will not solve the underlying conceptual problem. `B2` cannot be a subtype of `B1` in the way you define it.

> use nest out will bring you Nothing in type analysis which is not acceptable for me: I use wildcard to declared all types I needed, why you just bring me Nothing!!!

`Nothing` is the perfect expression of the fact that no type can satisfy all the generic constraints you defined at the same time (because they contradict each other).

---

EDIT: the conversation is getting quite long under @broot's answer, so let me have another stab at showing the problem with real things here.

In your first example, `A` and `B` aren't used anywhere, so let's remove them for simplicity. I'll rename `A1` to `Toy` and `BX` classes to animals for clarity.

You're trying to do this:

```kotlin
internal open class Toy<out T : Animal>(
    open val owner: T
) {
    fun amuseOwner() {
        owner.playWith(this)
    }
}

internal open class Animal(
    open val playWith: (Toy<Animal>) -> Unit
)

internal class Dog(
    override val playWith: (Toy<Dog>) -> Unit // thankfully does not compile
) : Animal(playWith)

internal class Cat(
    override val playWith: (Toy<Cat>) -> Unit // thankfully does not compile
) : Animal(playWith)

fun main() {
    val cat: Cat = Cat { catToy: Toy<Cat> -> /* do something */ }
    val dog: Dog = Dog { dogToy: Toy<Dog> -> /* do something */ }
    val catToy: Toy<Cat> = Toy(cat)

    val dogAnimal: Animal = dog // allowed by Liskov substitution principle
    dogAnimal.playWith(catToy) // should NOT be allowed, but compiles fine
}
```

Even though `Toy<Dog>` is indeed a subtype of `Toy<Animal>`, the function `(Toy<Dog>)->Unit` is NOT a subtype of `(Toy<Animal>)->Unit` - it's in fact a *supertype* of it.

You can see that it's conceptually incorrect to want at the same time that `Animal` can `playWith` any `Toy<Animal>`, but that `Dog` can only play with `Toy<Dog>` - if that is so, `Dog` cannot be an `Animal` in the OO sense, because it cannot play with `Toy<Cat>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I got two points for your answer:

Fisrt, you are right on the Nothing, though my codes can go to compile, it will always fail on type cast. :-(

Second, about the type cast problem, I am really new on both kotlin & stack overflow and maybe I didn't make myself clear in question, more detailed explain is not replied to broot and I hope that will help.

Comment: @michael I updated my answer with animal analogy, I hope this clarifies the conceptual problem

Comment: Thanks for updated example but that is not what I am seeking for. I updated my question with named example and hope that helps. I want doSth stored in state provides contravariant argument.      -->--My solution-->--Now I give up to do that in kotlin and make java classes instead. As far as I found, kotlin do less derivation than java for nested contravariant. The quick example is Apple<Apple> is safe to be consumed as Fruit<Fruit>, but kotlin doesn't do that cast for me.

Comment: While using nested contravariant, kotlin simply do its logic ( I am not very sure about how it consider and didn't do research ) and gives NOTHING. The NOTHING inferred by kotlin actually could be sth

Comment: In my updated case, event excutors could be ignored, just focusing on state generations and you will see nested contravariant doesn't work well in kotlin

Comment: @michael *Now I give up to do that in kotlin and make java classes instead* - please share your java code as well. My bet is that it is broken but the Java compiler doesn't see that. Or you're not defining the same thing (as broot pointed out, you don't override the field in Java, you just shadow it)

Comment: I updated a java example at UPDATE2 in question body and now I got a question for stackoverflow, why I cannot do at + J + tab to show quick complete of your name :-(, that works for broot.

Comment: looks like I cannot at you, is that a privacy settings of stackoverflow, even when I type your name, it will be removed after I click send